# Combine object with array as list of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an Object as

```
var a ={
demo:[1,2,3],
demo1:[test1,test2,test3]
}`
```

I want to convert the above object into array of objects

```
var a = [{"demo":"1", "demo1":"test1"},{"demo":"2", "demo1":"test2"},{"demo":"3", "demo1":"test3"}];`
```

can anyone help on this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate on the first array - `demo`, using [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and then using the *index* of the first item access the `demo1` appropriate item.

```js
const a = {
   demo: [1, 2, 3],
   demo1: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
};

const mapped = a.demo.map((item, index) => ({ demo: item, demo1: a.demo1[index] }));

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to iterate through your array and using `Object#keys()` you can get the key of each object then iterate through each key and add to an accumulator object.

```js
var a = [{"demo":"1", "demo1":"test1"},{"demo":"2", "demo1":"test2"},{"demo":"3", "demo1":"test3"}],
  result = a.reduce((r,o) => {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
      r[k] = r[k] || [];
      r[k].push(o[k]);
    });
    return r;
  },{});
console.log(result);
```